# Phalcon custom validate message is not showing

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

I have app/model/user.php

here is the validation in the model

```
    public function validation() {

       $this->validation->add(new EmailValidate(array(
           'field' => 'email',
           'message' => 'Please enter a valid Email address'
       )));
    }
```

When I submit the form it display "email is required" instead of "Please enter a valid Email address"

do I miss something?

Comment: Is your html element for email containing `required` attribute?

Comment: @aksappy: actually, no

Comment: @aksappy: that's client-side validation, is it?

Comment: Yes that is, are you having this after a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your code. You are trying to add a new validator to `$this->validation`. Unless you have extended your own `Model` base class it should be:

```
public function validation() {

   $this->add(new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email(array(
       'field' => 'email',
       'message' => 'Please enter a valid Email address'
   )));
}
```

Because the validator was not added the `email is required` message comes from the `NOT NULL` constraint on the table.